# display image contained in a link on an imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to display the image in this link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11469423/m6.jpg
in an imageview. i referred to some posts and i did it the following way:

```
URL url = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11469423/m6.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
mIVPic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

but at runtime, the imageview is displayng nothing.

please let me know why the image in the link is not getting displayed on the imageview and how to do it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at the [picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Then you can do things like

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
       .into(imageView);
```